# Azure Data Factory global parameters don't work with new deployment method

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I'm using the "new" ADF deployment approach as defined here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements#continuous-deployment-improvements

Which pulls code out of the collabaration branch and validates and compiles it using this code:

(sample of validation code straight from the site - my code uses real values and runs as expected)

```
run build validate $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/<Root-folder-from-Git-configuration-settings-in-ADF> /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/testResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<Your-Factory-Name>
```

This works fine for me. The output of the build stage is an ARM template that can be deployed.

However when I start using global parameters I get this error:

> Validator: Error for Expression:
> '@pipeline().globalParameters.gAFConnectivityTestEndPoint', Expression
> Error Message: 'Parameter gAFConnectivityTestEndPoint was not found
> under MYRESOURCEGROUP-001', attribute:
> '{"name":"url","display":"url","constraint":{},"primitive":true,"templatable":true,"_owner":{"name":"WebActivity","display":["Activity","Activities"]}}',
> obj:
> '{"_object":{},"_owned":{},"_ancestor":{},"_model":{},"_aObject":{}}',
> resolution: '{"kind":0,"details":{}}', resolution.error:
> '{"kind":0,"details":{}}'

The doco seems to indicate that global parameters are not published to the collabaration branch, *however* I've found that global parameters are acually written into the `factory/ADFName.JSON` file in the collabaration branch. So it appears to have all required information.

I've tried copying the global parameters JSON file into the collabaration branch from the adf_publish branch with the same filename and get the same error

Does anyone know what is required to get this working? How do I tell the npm task about my global parameters JSON?

## EDIT

I tried to repro for a much simpler pipeline and the npm task executed with no errors so it seems like this does work. Ticking "Include in ARM template" was not necessary for this to work. I need to work out why it fails for my more complicated pipeline. Curiously the error refers to the resource group, not the adf instance, so perhaps it is because the failing environment is heavily locked down.

Answer (score 0):

Are your Global Parameters included in the ARM Template? There are two ways via which you can deploy the Global Parameters:

1. Via ARM Template
2. Via PowerShell

To include them in the ARM Template JSON file you will have to check *Include in ARM Template* checkbox in the Global Parameter window under Manage section

[image]

Please refer to the below link to deploy Global Parameters in ADF as they do have some limitations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters#cicd

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, whether or not "Include in ARM template" is ticked, the global parameters will not be included in collabaration branch, only the adf_publish branch. Also the parameter deployment scfript occurs long after this npm task that is failing _The doco makes it clear that global parameters JSON is never published to the collabaration branch, so it's no suprise that the validation step fails as there is no definition of global parameters_

Comment: If that is the case then a support ticket with MS can be raised for this and I would say a resort to this can be addition of Global Parameters manually after deployment or via Powershell as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters#cicd

Comment: Yes I've tried adding manually, but i don't know what format then npm task is expecting to be able to recognise them. I've already raised a document ticket, but I don't have a MS account to raise as an issue

Comment: This can be raised from Azure Portal for ADF component and they will include the Deployment team in the ticket. Can you try Powershell method?

Comment: I can't try the powershell method, because that occurs at the deploy stage. The problem I'm having occurs during the _build_ stage. I can't actually build an artifact that can be deployed

Comment: I realised that global parameters actually are included in the collabaration branch, which still raises the quesion of why the npm task fails to validate.

Comment: If possible please share screenshot where the failure occurs in the process, is the npm script correctly installing packages?

Comment: Is the issue resolved?